# Download twilio record in my dataBase #10

Tags: database, twilio, action, record, twilio-twiml

I used the "action" option of twiML to send the recording of a call to my application and add the url and the text of call in my database

but it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response> <Dial record="true" > +######## </Dial> <Record method="POST" action="http://myapp.com/phone_call/speech.php" timeout="10" /> </Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to record a call, which I assume is what you are trying to do.

You want to use the Record attribute (and associated recordingStatusCallback) of the Dial Verb. The TwiML Record verb is used for recording voice mails, as an example.

[TwiML™ Voice:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#record)

[Recording Incoming Twilio Voice Calls](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010317333-Recording-Incoming-Twilio-Voice-Calls)

Comment: the record it's ok but  in speech.php i don't receive $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'] (the url of recording file)

Comment: You can check the Twilio console debugger (little bug icon in upper right corner), if you are not seeing the recordingStatusCallback hitting speech.php, maybe there is some error. The correct key being sent is RecordingUrl, as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Done :)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial record="true"          recordingStatusCallback="https://myapp.com/call/speech.php"
          recordingStatusCallbackEvent="completed"  >
      +##########
  </Dial>

</Response>
```